# notificaciones push android studio

Tags: android

He leído algo sobre que se pueden hacer notificaciones flotantes del tipo llamadas entrantes, pero no encuentro la manera de hacerlas.
Acabo de ponerme con las notificaciones y las simples funcionan bien pero no se como hacer una flotante.

Por otro lado creo un icono con sus distintos tamaños etc pero al poner el icono en la notificación sale mal, se ve el circulo verdeazulado típico y dentro el icono pequeñito. No se si hay alguna manera para que el icono ocupe todo el circulo o almenos que aparezca mas grande.

Otra pregunta mas. Al lanzar una notificacion, si hay una ya lanzada, la sobreescribe, de manera que aunque debiera tener 2 o más, solo puedo tener 1 a la vez. Como soluciono eso?

Codigo de las notificaciones:

```
        intent = new Intent(this,cocina.class);
        pending = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,0);


        notificacion = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        notificacion.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.camarero);
        notificacion.setContentTitle("Restaurante");
        notificacion.setContentText("Se ha actualizado el pedido de la mesa 1");
        notificacion.setContentIntent(pending);
        notificacion.setAutoCancel(true);
        notificacion.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.camarero));

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(notificacion_id,notificacion.build());
```

Comment: he conseguido poner el icono a tamaño completo pero sale un circulito abajo a la derecha que no se quitar

Comment: Hola miklotov considera agregar codigo e imagenes para que tus preguntas sean mejores.

Comment: El código de esta página web me ha ayudado mucho a desarrollar notificaciones push, espero que a ti también te sirva.
* https://web-push-book.gauntface.com/demos/notification-examples/